# Install binary dependencies on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, imagemagick, ghostscript

I need to convert PDF to PNG on heroku, i'm using RMagick and for some PDF i run into this error :

> Ghostscript 8.628.62: : Unrecoverable error, exit code 1 Unrecoverable

The same code runs fine on my local machine using Ghostscript 9.05

I would like to update the version of Ghostscript being used on Heroku and see if that solves the problem.
I followed these instruction to build ghostscript 9.05 on heroku :

http://theprogrammingbutler.com/blog/archives/2011/07/28/running-pdftotext-on-heroku/

My problem is vendoring the resulting package, **how can i tell heroku to use my custom version of ghostscript instead of the system one ?**

Here is what i tried :

- Add the gs package under vendor/ghostscript/bin
- Add it to the heroku path : heroku config:add PATH=vendor/ghostscript/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

My app still run on GS 8.62

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Here are some ressources i tried to follow without success ...

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries

http://www.ryandaigle.com/a/using-vulcan-to-build-binary-dependencies-on-heroku

Comment: Doesn't RMagick use ImageMagick (which then uses GS)? Reading up on how to tell IM to use a different version of GS the advice is often 'reinstall IM' so could you try installing a custom version of IM?

Comment: This is exactly what i'm trying to do : how can you install a binary on Heroku ? ImageMagick, Ghostscript, PDFTK, my question basically applies to any binary.